# Unicode formatting compiler warning: Format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'int'

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unicode, nsstring

It's a tad OCD, but I hate getting any compiler warnings. When I updated XCode, I started getting this compiler warning:

> Format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'int'

When I tried including the Unicode character for degree using the following code:

```
currentVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%C", angleDeg, 0x00B0];
```

How do I make the compiler warning go away, either by changing the code or turning off that particular compiler warning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cast the literal to `unichar`:

```
currentVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%C", angleDeg, (unichar)0x00B0];
```